# Knockout mapping options not excluding additional properties from source object

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-mapping-plugin

In my view model I've declared an observable property called 'MappedItem':

```
var MyViewModel = function () {
    var $scope = this;

    ...

    $scope.MappedItem = ko.observable();

    ...
```

I need to map an object called 'item', which has several properties. I only need three of them in my mapped observable. So, here's what I'm trying:

```
var mapping = {'include': ["recid", "Program", "Station"]};
$scope.MappedItem = ko.mapping.fromJS(item, mapping);
```

This works but my mapping rules are ignored and I end up with 'MappedItem' having a lot of useless observable properties.

To get what I want I have to explicitly declare every property I don't want mapped in the 'ignore' attribute of the mapping options object:

```
var mapping = {
   'ignore': ["AdLength", "Affiliate", ... (MANY OTHER PROPERTIES MORE) ],
   'include': ["recid", "Program", "Station"]
};
$scope.MappedItem = ko.mapping.fromJS(item, mapping);
```

Another approach that I've tried:

```
ko.mapping.fromJS(item, mapping, $scope.MappedItem);
```

But this does not map any of 'item' properties to 'MappedItem' at all.

**Shouldn't I be able to map the needed properties only using the 'include', without having to explicitly declare them in the 'ignore' option?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 'include' array is only useful whenever you are mapping an item more than once. For instance, let's say you have mapped an item. Later on, you map the same item again, except this time, three additional properties have been added to the item. By default, Knockout would ignore those additional three properties because they weren't there the first time. By customizing the 'include' array, you can force Knockout to map those additional three properties.

Unfortunately the 'include' array does not act as a whitelist like you were expecting.

As a work around, you can customize the mapping object using the 'create' function, and only include the properties that you desire:

**Javascript**

```
var item = {
  'recid': '0',
  'Program': 'TestProgram',
  'Station': 'TestStation',
  'ignoredProperty': 'test'
};

var mapping = {
  create: function(options) {
    var orig = options.data;
    var filtered = {
      'recid': ko.observable(orig.recid),
      'Program': ko.observable(orig.Program),
      'Station': ko.observable(orig.Station)
    };
    return filtered;
  }
};

var myViewModel = function() {
  var $scope = this;
  $scope.MappedItem = ko.mapping.fromJS(item, mapping);
};

var vm = new myViewModel();
ko.applyBindings(vm);
```

**Fiddle:** https://jsfiddle.net/dw1284/g8ca78kc/

Answer (score 0):

**include**

When you map your **existing** `view model` back to a `JS object`, by default the mapping plugin only includes those properties that are part of your `existing view model`, unless you `include` those that are not.

**ignore**

When you want to `ignore` some properties of your `JS object` once you want the mapping plugin creates a view model for you, you can specify them as an array of name that needs to be ignored.

That's why when you are creating a `view model`, the mapping plugin just takes whatever you've specified in `ignore` array and it actually denies your `include` which makes sense.

To do what you want since you want to have only three properties out of many, I suggest to create a sub view model manually with those three observable variables then you won't have many useless variables on your model.

```
 var MyViewModel = function () {
    var $scope = this;
    ...
    $scope.MappedItem = ko.observableArray();
    $scope.MappedItem($.map(items, function (item) {
         return new ItemViewModel(item);
    })); 
}

var ItemViewModel = function (data) {
    var $scope = this;
    $scope.recid = ko.observableArray(data.recid);
    $scope.Program = ko.observableArray(data.Program);
    $scope.Station = ko.observableArray(data.Station);
}
```